# Can't fix ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

I'm following [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O1vQABTMMgo&list=PLFUqwj4q1Zr8GHs6bO4d6gxMGUh_2pcNg&index=3). This problem is near the 6th minute of the video.
I've modified some variables that are shown in the video.

I created a **40x20** map to later use it when initializing `TileGrid`.

```
int[][] map = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
    };
```

I initialized `TileGrid` and passed the integer *two-dimensional* array `map` as an argument.

```
TileGrid grid = new TileGrid(map);
```

`TileGrid`'s constructor is the following:

```
public Tile[][] map;
// Determines how many tiles can fit in the screen, in total it can fit 40x20 tiles.
// Artist.WIDTH is the window's width and Artist.HEIGHT is the window's height.
private int tilesAX = Artist.WIDTH / Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_WIDTH;
private int tilesAY = Artist.HEIGHT / Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_HEIGHT;

public TileGrid(int[][] newMap)
{
    map = new Tile[tilesAX][tilesAY];
    for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(newMap[i][j] == 0)
                map[i][j] = new Tile(i * Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_WIDTH, j * Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_HEIGHT, Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_WIDTH, Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_HEIGHT, TileType.Grass);
            else
                map[i][j] = new Tile(i * Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_WIDTH, j * Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_HEIGHT, Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_WIDTH, Tile.DEFAULT_TILE_HEIGHT, TileType.Dirt);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
    at me.bermudez.tiles.TileGrid.<init>(TileGrid.java:31)
    at me.bermudez.Boot.<init>(Boot.java:39)
    at me.bermudez.Boot.main(Boot.java:84)
```

.

`me.bermudez.tiles.TileGrid.<init>(TileGrid.java:31)` refers to the following line of code:

```
if(newMap[i][j] == 0)
```

I'm not sure if the amount of information I gave is enough to explain the problem. I've tried to explain everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `tilesAX` and `tilesAY` are obviously larger than your predefined 40x20 map.

Comment: I thought programming was about making the computer do the job you don't want to do. Like instantiating a matrix with eight hundred elements...

Comment: @Dici The code is not mine. I'm following a tutorial.

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez Step #1 is to find a *different* 'tutorial'.

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez then you should do better than you tutorial. You don't even know if you counted well the number of rows and cols. It's as simple as `new int[40][20]`

Comment: Why that `if` statement is for?

Comment: @Dici I did as you said and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @MaxZoom for determining the type of tile, but it is an ugly way to do it

Comment: It has to be something else, because all elements are zero at the begging. from the initial array

Comment: The matrix is 20x40 by the way, not 40x20

Comment: I'm not sure If I should answer this question myself - since after doing what @Dici said - it worked. I don't know HOW it worked though.

Comment: I'm posting an answer for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer to this is that ugly code is also often *broken*. The code assumes that `newMap` and `map` have the same size, or more precisely that `newMap` is bigger (more rows and more cols) than `map`.

It was not the case, for many reasons :

- the size of `map` was computed at runtime, whereas the size of `newMap` was hardcoded. If you replaced it with `new int[40][20]`, you still have this problem and it will break whenever `map` will have a different size in a different runtime context
- you thought you were instantiating a 40x20 array, but it was a 20x40 array

All of this leads to a single conclusion : know your language, know its constructs, and as soon as you realize you are doing a stupid and boring task as filling a 800 elements array by hand (or by copy-paste), ask yourself if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

the upper bounds of an array is map.length - 1, in your loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    // do something
}
```

and

```
for(int j = 0; j < map[i].length; j++){
    // do something
}
```

the upper bounds should be map.length - 1 and map[i].length - 1

Comment: I think you meant `j` instead of `i` in your second loop

Comment: Thank you for correcting that, it is my bad, I just copy and paste the first loop :P

Comment: You should not show two apparently unrelated pieces of code which are actually related. I think you meant to make the second loop an inner loop of the first one

Comment: Ummm, why????  This code uses `<`, which means that `i` and `j` will never be `map.length` or `map[i].length`.  This is a standard idiom.